# When did WPARAM change from being signed to unsigned?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In Delphi 6 `WPARAM` is declared as being signed:

```
WPARAM = Longint;
```

In Delphi 2010 `WPARAM` is declared as being signed:

```
WPARAM = INT_PTR;
```

But in XE2 it is declared as being unsigned:

```
WPARAM = UINT_PTR;
```

The official [Windows definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28VS.85%29.aspx) is:

```
typedef UINT_PTR WPARAM;
```

This matches with XE2.

---

Does anyone know whether the change was made for XE or for XE2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Delphi XE `WPARAM = INT_PTR;`  so the change was introduced in XE2.

Comment: Thank you. That means there's more risk with my current migration to XE2 than I had anticipated.

Comment: @David Heffernan - would you care to explain that? AFAIK, it should not be a problem unless you have been using negative WPARAM's somewhere.

Comment: @Lieven I've come across code with tests like `WParam>=0`. There's a whole class of potential bugs here that will be quite hard to find.

Comment: In Delphi XE2 many data type aliases (in WinAPI units) where changed to the original data types that are used in Microsofts WinAPI header files. WPARAM should have never been declared as Longint (in Delphi 2). Now they fixed all data types to get them working in 64 bit Delphi.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. Do you know which other types have had their definitions changed/corrected? P.S. Still loving your fabulous Delphi enhancements!

Comment: @David Will the compiler not "catch" those potential bugs with the _widened both operands_ warning?

Comment: @NGLN No it won't because no widening is needed. `WParam>=0` gets caught by the "always evaluates to True" warning, but `WParam>0` will not be caught and has completely different meaning.

Comment: Interestingly MSDN declares WPARAM values of -1 for some methods as having a special meaning. Actually MS doesn't really care of handling negative values in a word. Just have a look at the WMPARAM description of WM_MOUSEWHEEL. "The high-order word indicates the distance the wheel is rotated, expressed in multiples or divisions of WHEEL_DELTA, which is 120. A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated forward, away from the user; a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated backward, toward the user."

Comment: A history follow up in ´The Old New Thing´ (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/29/10181137.aspx).